# Site not opening only in IE

Tags: php, mysql

This is my site done using PHP, MYSQL and MVC Architecture.

this site is loading in all the browsers but not in IE.

I can't even able to judge the problem. How to resolve this?

Any help will be appreciable and grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got error http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/src/controller/GoodyController.php?cityname=johannesburg&action=city

Comment: Warning: require_once(/home/foursqua/public_html/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/src/vo/MaxVO.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/foursqua/public_html/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/src/controller/GoodyController.php on line 14

Comment: @@experimentX: kindly try the above edited URL. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i tried with `http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/` in `IE` all other pages are opening but not that specific page, match the code with other pages..must b some header problem can b there

even below one also opens

```
http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/view/
```

but that page, u specified , moves automatically to

```
http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/view/php/indexLand.php
```

there must be some header problem on

**http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies/view/php** folder

please check and review back..

Happy to Help :)

Comment: this folder (http://www.foursquareinfo.com/4sdev/CorePHP/Groopies) has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when you view the source in FF or another non-IE browser there are two lines of whitespace before the doctype declaration.  This can sometimes cause issues with Internet Explorer.  Try modifying your code so that the *very first line* on your page is the doctype declaration, that may correct the issue.

There must be something else going on as well though, because normally extra whitespace before the doctype is enough to cause some unexpected results but not a completely failed load.  I agree with [diEcho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho) that there must be a header problem in there somewhere.